# Deadlock-free locking multiple locks in Go

Tags: go, mutex

Is there a proven programmatic way to achieve mutual exclusion of multiple Mutexes / Locks / whatever in Golang?
Eg.

```
mutex1.Lock()
defer mutex1.Unlock()
mutex2.Lock()
defer mutex2.Unlock()
mutex3.Lock()
defer mutex3.Unlock()
```

would keep mutex1 locked I guess while waiting for mutex2 / mutex3. For several goroutines, all using a different subset of several locks, this easily can get deadlocked.

So is there any way to acquire those locks only if all of them are available? Or is there any other pattern (using channels maybe?) in achieving the same?

Comment: See also [the dining philosophers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem).

Comment: How to use channels for implementing mutual access to resources (functions) that may be used by several functions?

Comment: @dronus One good method is to implement a little goroutine service. On its service channel send it a request struct (look up a key in a map for example) and in the request include the channel to return the response on. A big benefit of this is if later you decide you need it, it becomes very easy to rewrite these to actual networked microservices.

Comment: @ZanLynx ok, but the channels of all services will serve in-order, or not? So if a job A needs some services for some time in parallel, but another job B also some of them, how to make sure the services are working for the right job? If any service just works on the first job coming, they may not conclude together, so they may never complete the compound job, and we have deadlock.

Comment: @dronus: If there is a situation like that it can usually be solved by using buffered channels. If it cannot be solved by buffered channels then you may have written a true circle of A -> B -> C -> A in which case you go back and design it from scratch.

Comment: Ok. Let's imagine a job trying two channels of two services. The job will take some time, so will will both services then. So if channel of service A ingests the request, but the other service B is still busy - how to prevent the request uselessly blocking service A, while waiting for service B coming available? For that we would need to 'redraw' the request out of the channel, until both channels are available simultaneously. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So is there any way to acquire those locks only if all of them are available?

No. Not with standard library mutex at least. There is no way to "check" if a lock is available, or "try" acquiring a lock. Every call of `Lock()` will block until locking is successful.

The implementation of mutex relies on atomic operations which only act on a single value at once. In order to achieve what you describe, you'd need some kind of "meta locking" where execution of the lock and unlock methods are themselves protected by a lock, but this probably isn't necessary just to have correct and safe locking in your program:

Penelope Stevens' comment explains correctly: As long as the order of acquisition is consistent between different goroutines, you won't get deadlocks, even for arbitrary subsets of the locks, if each goroutine eventually releases the locks it acquires.

If the structure of your program provides some obvious locking order, then use that. If not, you can create your own special mutex type that has intrinsic ordering.

```golang
type Mutex struct {
    sync.Mutex
    id uint64
}


var mutexIDCounter uint64
func NewMutex() *Mutex {
    return &Mutex{
        id: atomic.AddUint64(&mutexIDCounter, 1),
    }
}

func MultiLock(locks ...*Mutex) {
    sort.Slice(locks, func(i, j int) bool { return locks[i].id < locks[j].id })
    
    for i := range locks {
        locks[i].Lock()
    }
}

func MultiUnlock(locks ...*Mutex) {
    for i := range locks {
        locks[i].Unlock()
    }
}
```

Usage:

```golang
a := NewMutex()
b := NewMutex()
c := NewMutex()
    
MultiLock(a, b, c)
MultiUnlock(a, b, c)
```

Each mutex is assigned an incrementing ID, and unlocked in order of ID.

Try it for yourself in this [example program](https://play.golang.org/p/ulTWF5T2d9s) on the playground. To prevent the deadlock, change `const safe = true`.

Comment: Looks sane, if the same set of locks is acquired every time (which then also could be replaced by a single lock, so not useful) like in the demo.  So I've tested this with trying to lock a lot of different subsets of all the three locks at the same time, and it _seem_ to work! But is there an easy explanation why this is so?

Comment: The simplest form of deadlock occurs when goroutine X tries to lock `a` then `b`, while goroutine Y tries to lock `b` then `a`. Each each acquires its first lock at the same time, then you'll have X waiting for Y to free `b`, and Y waiting for X to free `a`. Since there is no way for either of them to yield, they both will wait forever. With an intrinsic ordering of the locks, it's no longer possible for the two goroutines to take them in an opposing order like this.

Comment: A more complete answer requires graph theory. Think of each lock as a node in a directional graph. For any lock being acquired, draw a connection from that lock to each other lock already held by that process. If any cycle exists in the graph, you have a deadlock. Now add the intrinsic ordering of locks. Imagine that each node is placed along some axis and sorted, and the connections are arrows. With the enforced locking order, now every arrow will point in the same direction (as each lock can only depend on a lock of a lesser order). With each arrow pointing the same way, cycles cannot exist.

Comment: Ah I see...  so I will edit the answer stating clearly that it won't deadlock on any subset of locks taken by any job, as long as the order is kept.

Answer (score -1):

You might as well just put all the Mutexes into an array or into a map and implement a function that will call Lock() method on each of those using range based loop, so the order of locking remains the same.

The function might also take an array containing indexes it shall skip(or not skip if you like).

This way there will be no way to change the order of locking the mutexes as the order of the loop is consistent.

Comment: The order of range on a map is not deterministic. Non-deterministic locking order will deadlock.